# Specify taskbar icon for a MessageBox

Tags: .net, winforms

How do I specify which icon a `MessageBox` should use in the taskbar? There are no `MessageBox.Show` overloads which let me select a taskbar icon, only an icon to use in the actual form.

Comment: Why do you have a `MessageBox` show up on the taskbar anyway? The only way that can happen is if you don't assign it a parent.

Comment: Since it's plugins that show the message boxes and they do not have access to the main form.

Comment: Maybe you should not allow/expect your plugins to display UI on their own. Provide them with a reference to an interface (like IMessageBox) that they can invoke on. Than you, as the host app, can provide a proper implementation (including parent, etc.).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I don't think it's possible to change the taskbar icon; your only option would be to make your own MessageBox.

Answer (score 3):

Short answer: You can't.

Short answer #2: You need to make your own form for this, and display it manually.

Answer (score 3):

To be able to show an Icon for a `MessageBox` at Task bar, I found a way to avoid creating custom form, but somehow we will create a dummy form (or you can change it into anonymous form):

```
        using (Form dummy = new Form() { 
                        Icon = Properties.Resources.ico_Main_Logo
                        , TopMost = true 
                        , FormBorderStyle = System.Windows.Forms.FormBorderStyle.None
                        , Size = new System.Drawing.Size(0,0)
                        , BackColor = Color.White
                        , TransparencyKey = Color.White
                    })
        {
            dummy.Show();
            MessageBox.Show(dummy, "This is a MessageBox with Icon at Taskbar and on top of all windows", "Title Text", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
        }
```

With above way, these useful features will be possible:

- Show Icon for `MessageBox` at Task Bar. (I use Application Setting to load an Icon, you can do it from Disk or ...)
- Show `MessageBox` window at Top of other windows. (if you do not want it then set `TopMost = false` )
- Do not show `MessageBox` Icon at Task bar. (Just initial a simple Form at usage and remove `dummy.Show();` line.)

Or just initial anonymous Form like this to hide `MessageBox` Icon from  Task bar:

```
MessageBox.Show(new Form(), "This is a MessageBox Hide it from Taskbar", "Title Text", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
```

Anyway, I just want share my new founds so it may help others too. Thank you.

This works fine, ***But I do not know why*** even when I set `Size` of Form to `(0, 0)` it still have a size of 131x37!!! But because the Form set as Transparency, It will be not visible and mouse pointer will click trough.